# matplotlib: изменение размера шрифта

Tags: python, matplotlib

Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно изменить размер шрифта подписей графика, построенного с помощью matplotlib? График строю так:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

values = [7, 3, 10]
times = [1, 3, 5]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(values, times)
plt.title('зависимость значения от времени')
plt.xlabel('время')
plt.ylabel('значение')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Передайте дополнительный параметр fontsize в методы xlabel, ylabel. Например `plt.xlabel('время', fontsize=42)`. [Описание метода xlabel](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel)

Comment: @godva, спасибо, хорошая идея. А можно глобально изменить размер шрифта, чтобы не передавать каждый раз?

Comment: Можно попробовать так `matplotlib.rc('axes', labelsize=42)`

Comment: @godva, спасибо, работает, увеличивает размер шрифта подписей к осям. для увеличения размера шрифта заголовка надо ещё раз тот же метод вызвать, с`titlesize` вместо `labelsize`